# Amazon Cognito Identity Pool Region not exist

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

My identity pool start with "us-east-2...". but I cannot find US_EAST_2 region in Android Cognito SDK. Probably region not supported by Amazon. When I create CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider object :

```
public static CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentialsProvider() {

        if (credentialsProvider == null) {
            credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context,
                    "us-east-2:*****", // Identity pool ID
                    Regions.DEFAULT_REGION);


        }
        return credentialsProvider;
    }
```

I show this message on logcat:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.ResourceNotFoundException: IdentityPool 'us-east-2:****' not found. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: ***)
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Regions cann't be default try to replace with Regions.US_EAST_1 .If i am not wrong

Comment: I tried US_EAST_1 before. i am getting same error.

Comment: Ok Try to use Regions.US_EAST_2 please.

Comment: US_EAST_2 region not exist. Please read my question.

Comment: So sorry i totally forgot

Comment: Did you ever solve this? The SDK still doesn't seem to have it

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the SDK to the latest version. Can you set your gradle dependencies to consume SDK version `2.6.0` instead of the ones you have e.g. `2.3.2`? That should fix the error. Some of the newer regions are only available in latest versions.

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: So this is 3 years old but still the amazon sdk does not have Regions.US_EAST_2, how is this possible?